# Creating a Generic Template Interface/Class and injecting into another object

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to create a generic template class for my document processor. Assuming the template has a source file path and a "content", here's what I came up with:

**Template**

```
public interface ITemplate<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The filepath of the base document for the template.
    /// </summary>
    String BaseDocumentFilePath { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the underlying template source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>T</returns>
    T GetContent();
}
public class WordTemplate : ITemplate<XmlDocument>
{
    private string _baseDocumentFilePath;
    private XmlDocument _content;

    public WordTemplate(XmlDocument content, string baseDocumentFilepath)
    {
        _content = content;
        _baseDocumentFilePath = baseDocumentFilepath;
    }

    public string BaseDocumentFilePath { get { return _baseDocumentFilePath;}}

    public XmlDocument GetContent()
    {
        return _content;
    }
}
```

**Ex Doc Generator**

```
public interface IDocumentGenerator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a document from an instance of <see cref="ITemplate"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="template">The template for the document.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDocumentFilepath">The full file path of the result output.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns filepath for generated document.</returns>
    void Generate<T>(ITemplate<T> template, string outputDocumentFilepath);
}

public class WordDocumentGenerator : IDocumentGenerator
{
    public void Generate<T>(ITemplate<T> template, string outputDocumentFilepath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocumentBody = template.GetContent() as XmlDocument;

        // generate doc
    }
}
```

The template would be created elsewhere and injected into the document generator. My question is, is this a good design? I am casting the generic `T` into XmlDocument (which is what I need for that specific implementation) and I don't think that's the right way to use generics. I've always been a little lost when it comes to generics.

Comment: You simply can't do `template.GetContent() as XmlDocument` unless `T` is `XmlDocument`. You need some sort of `Func<T, XmlDocument>` to make this work. Any why are you working with the old `XmlDocument` and not the newer `XDocument`?

Comment: I have finished implementing this...I removed the //generate doc portion for simplicity. If this isn't the place for design review, where is the proper place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template related class and interface are looking good to me. But the generator related class and interface are flawed.

Assume one would call the `Generate()` method with an `ITemplate<string>` which would be totally legal. Sure it would work, but `xmlDocumentBody` would be `null`.

You could if the passed in template isn't a `ITemplate<XmlDocument>` throw some exception, but a user of this class wouldn't expect for a generic class which is **called correctly** to get an exception.

So you should better make the `IDocumentGenerator` generic and not the `Generate()` method.

```
public interface IDocumentGenerator<T>
{
    void Generate(ITemplate<T> template, string outputDocumentFilepath);
}
```

and now your `WordDocumentGenerator` class should implement `IDocumentGenerator<XmlDocument>` like

```
public class WordDocumentGenerator : IDocumentGenerator<XmlDocument>
{
    public void Generate<T>(ITemplate<XmlDocument> template, string outputDocumentFilepath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocumentBody = template.GetContent();

        // generate doc
    }
}
```

For sure if you have different types of templates you should add a `DocumentGeneratorFactory` which returns the desired `DocumentGenerator` for the task at hand.